# The coding in hp vertica

Tags: vertica

I installed the latest version of the free hp vertica server on OS Linux CentOS release 6.6 (Final). Next, I set up a server and created a database IM_0609. Next, I created a table with the command:

```
CREATE TABLE MARKS (SERIAL_NUM  varchar(30),PERIOD smallint,MARK_NUM decimal(20,0), END_MARK_NUM decimal(20,0),OLD_MARK_NUM decimal(20,0),DEVICE_NAME varchar(256),DEVICE_MARK varchar(256),CALIBRATION_DATE date);
```

Next, from the DB2 database I executed EXPORT data to txt file:

```
5465465|12|+5211.|+5211.||Комплексы компьютеризированные самостоятельного предрейсового экспресс-обследования функционального состояния машиниста, водителя и оператора|ЭкОЗ-01|2004-12-09
5465465|12|+5211.|+5211.||Спектрометры эмиссионные|Metal Lab|2004-12-09
б/н|12|+5207.|+5207.|+5205.|Спектрометры эмиссионные|Metal Lab|2004-12-09
б/н|12|+5207.|+5207.|+5205.|Спектрометры эмиссионные|Metal Test|2004-12-09
....
```

and I changed the file encoding to UTF-8.
I then import the data from the text file into a database table using the hp vertica here this command:

```
copy MARKS from '/home/dbadmin/result.txt' delimiter '|' null as '' exceptions '/home/dbadmin/copy-error.log' ABORT ON ERROR;
```

All data loaded, but Russian characters display some weird characters, apparently this is due to the problems of character encoding the command COPY.

```
5465465 12  5211    5211    (null)  Êîìïëåêñû êîìïüşòåğèçèğîâàííûå ñàìîñòîÿòåëüíîãî ïğåäğåéñîâîãî ıêñïğåññ-îáñëåäîâàíèÿ ôóíêöèîíàëüíîãî ñîñòîÿíèÿ ìàøèíèñòà, âîäèòåëÿ è îï  İêÎÇ-01 2004-12-09
5465465 12  5211    5211    (null)  Ñïåêòğîìåòğû ıìèññèîííûå    Metal Lab   2004-12-09
```

Question: How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What did you do to change the file encoding to UTF-8?

Comment: You can change the encoding on the Vertica side to preserve the Russian letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your file encoding us **utf-8**

```
[dbadmin@DCG023 ~]$ file rus
rus: UTF-8 Unicode text

[dbadmin@DCG023 ~]$ cat rus
5465465|12|+5211.|+5211.||Комплексы компьютеризированные самостоятельного предрейсового экспресс-обследования функционального состояния машиниста, водителя и оператора|ЭкОЗ-01|2004-12-09
5465465|12|+5211.|+5211.||Спектрометры эмиссионные|Metal Lab|2004-12-09
б/н|12|+5207.|+5207.|+5205.|Спектрометры эмиссионные|Metal Lab|2004-12-09
б/н|12|+5207.|+5207.|+5205.|Спектрометры эмиссионные|Metal Test|2004-12-09
```

**Load the data**

```
[dbadmin@DCG023 ~]$ vsql
Password:
Welcome to vsql, the Vertica Analytic Database interactive terminal.

Type:  \h or \? for help with vsql commands
       \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
       \q to quit

(dbadmin@:5433) [dbadmin] > copy MARKS from '/home/dbadmin/rus' delimiter '|' null as ''  ABORT ON ERROR;
 Rows Loaded
-------------
           4
(1 row)
```

**Query the data**

```
(dbadmin@:5433) [dbadmin] > select * from Marks;
 SERIAL_NUM | PERIOD | MARK_NUM | END_MARK_NUM | OLD_MARK_NUM |                                                              DEVICE_NAME                                                               | DEVICE_MARK | CALIBRATION_DATE
------------+--------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+------------------
 5465465    |     12 |     5211 |         5211 |              | Комплексы компьютеризированные самостоятельного предрейсового экспресс-обследования функционального состояния машиниста, водителя и оп | ЭкОЗ-01     | 2004-12-09
 5465465    |     12 |     5211 |         5211 |              | Спектрометры эмиссионные                                                                                                               | Metal Lab   | 2004-12-09
 б/н        |     12 |     5207 |         5207 |         5205 | Спектрометры эмиссионные                                                                                                               | Metal Lab   | 2004-12-09
 б/н        |     12 |     5207 |         5207 |         5205 | Спектрометры эмиссионные                                                                                                               | Metal Test  | 2004-12-09
(4 rows)
```